# how to select specific rows in some condition

Tags: mysql

I tried to write a query that selects rows with steps that both user 1 and user 2 did, with combined number of times they did the step (i.e., if user 1 did step 1 3 times and user 2 did 1 time then the count should show 4 times.)

when I put condition as user_id=1, user_id=2 there is no error but it return nothing, when it should return some rows with values.

there is table step, and step taken 
and table step has column id, title 
    table step_taken has column id, user_id(who performs steps), step_id

i want to find step that both of two user whose id 1,2 did 
and also want to have the value as count added up how many times they performed that step.

for example if user id 1 did step named meditation 2 times, 
            and user id 2 did step named meditation 3 times,
the result i want to find should be like below ;

```
------------------------------
  title   |  number_of_times
------------------------------
meditation|        5
------------------------------
```

here is my sql query

```
select title, count(step_taken.step_id)as number_of_times
from step join step_taken
on step.id = step_taken.step_id
where user_id = 1 and user_id=2
group by title;
```

it returns nothing, but it should return some rows of step both user1 and user 2 did.

when i wrote same thing only with user_id=1 or user_id=2, it shows selected information

how can I fix my code so it can show the information I want to get?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user_id cannot be 1 and 2 at the same time. You need a second user table. Then join those on your criteria and count:

```
select title, count(u1.id) + count(u2.id) as number_of_times
from step u1 join step u2
on u1.id = u2.id
where u1.user_id = 1 and u2.user_id=2
group by title;
```

note: cannot tell what table title is in, or the purpose of `step_taken` was as `step.id` is identical.

Comment: @sjk if this solved your problem, please accept so that it may help others.